# WPF Closing event not fired in windows 7?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a C# window, and just found that the right click close event on taskbar under windows 7 is not fired.

[image]

However on my developing windows 10 PC, this action is properly handled.
My xaml file looks like below:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WCSevenX"
    x:Class="WCSevenX.MainWindow"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"                
    Loaded="Window_Loaded" 
    Closing="OnClosing"  
    Background="#B0CBCBE5" 
    Name="MainWnd" 
    Unloaded="MainWnd_Unloaded" 
    SizeChanged="MainWnd_SizeChanged" 
    PreviewGotKeyboardFocus="MainWnd_PreviewGotKeyboardFocus" 
    PreviewLostKeyboardFocus="MainWnd_PreviewLostKeyboardFocus" 
    GotFocus="MainWnd_GotFocus" 
    GotKeyboardFocus="MainWnd_GotKeyboardFocus">
    <!--body...-->
</Window>
```

And the OnClosing function is:

```
private void OnClosing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    //do something before close
    //...
    //close my window
    System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown();
    System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
}
```

Function `OnClosing` is called under windows 10, but not in windows 7. In windows 7, right click and close cannot close my window.

**UPDATE:**

Today I also tried catching the `WM_CLOSE` message in WndProc().

In windows 10, both [X] button and right click close on taskbar do receive `WM_CLOSE` message.
In windows 7, only [X] button receives `WM_CLOSE` message.

Is anywhere I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Try attaching the event from code, not from xaml :

```
 this.Closing += OnClosing;
```

For me this works both for both windows 7 and 10.

Hope this will work with you.

Comment: I added Closing event in code, but still not fired in windows 7 from taskbar right click.

Comment: Try using Closed event to see if it is fired or is the same case

Comment: Closed event is acting the same.

Answer (score 0):

manage the exit event in the application class

```
protected override void OnExit(ExitEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnExit(e);

        this.DispatcherUnhandledException -= new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventHandler(App_DispatcherUnhandledException);
    }
```

Comment: I am using a `Window` class, really need an `Application` class?

Comment: well it cost nothing and allow you to manage event that does not go through the main windows like alt+F4, .... look at this good sample :-)       http://wfpbookreader.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#CBR/CBR/Views/MainView.xaml

Comment: Strange, Application.OnExit event is not raised, in windows 7 from taskbar right click. Only the X button works.

Comment: it works for me in two projects....did try to compile all CBR code and test

Answer (score 0):

I found that I have a thread which has dispatcher:

```
private void StartDlg()
{
    wnd = new MyDlg();
    wnd.Show();
    Dispatcher.Run();  //<-this start an event loop
}
Thread myThread = new Thread(StartDlg);
```

After some searching, I knew that if I don't do

```
Dispatcher.FromThread(myThread).InvokeShutdown();
```

My thread will block the window message loop.

In windows 8+ it is fine, but in windows 7 this will block right click close message to deliver to my application. Adding `InvokeShutdown` will fix in windows 7.